# How to achieve in MySql what "retain" does in SAS?

Tags: mysql, sas, retain

I want to carry down the value of a variable from row 1 to row 2, use it for a calculation in row 2 and then take the output to row 3  in my query. The process repeats for 1000s of rows. Retain does this in SAS, how do I do it in MySql?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you would use subqueries for in-between observations calculations  and relate values between the nested and main query. Since typical uses of the [RETAIN](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm) statement in SAS involves running totals, counting number of value occurrences, setting indicators within a BY-group, nested subqueries can replicate such functionality.

The below example demonstrates running aggregates across grouped observations.

Example table

```
id  group               name       amount
1   Object-oriented     Java       100
2   Object-oriented     C#         50
3   Object-oriented     Python     75
4   Object-oriented     PHP        65
5   Special Purpose     SQL        80
6   Special Purpose     XSLT       60
7   Statistical         R          85
8   Statistical         SAS        100
```

Query with two subqueries for running counts and running sums:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group, t1.name, t1.amount, 
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM maintable As t2 
    WHERE t1.group = t2.group AND t1.id >= t2.id) As RunningCount,
   (SELECT Sum(t3.amount) FROM maintable As t3 
    WHERE t1.group = t3.group AND t1.id >= t3.id) As RunningAmount
FROM maintable As t1
```

Output

```
id  group              name    amount   RunningCount    RunningAmount
1   Object-oriented    Java    100      1               100
2   Object-oriented    C#      50       2               150
3   Object-oriented    Python  75       3               225
4   Object-oriented    PHP     65       4               290
5   Special Purpose    SQL     80       1               80
6   Special Purpose    XSLT    60       2               140
7   Statistical        R       85       1               85
8   Statistical        SAS     100      2               185
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, i tried something similar and got an error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: SELECT 
 T1.UID,  
 T1.discount_bucket ,
 T1.discount_id,
 T1.subcatid, 
 T1.brandid , 
 T1.num_cb_requests , 
 T1.recom_pog,
 T1.App, 
 T1.Remain,

(Select
(CASE WHEN (T2.recom_pog>T2.num_cb_requests ) THEN (T2.recom_pog-T2.num_cb_requests+T1.Remain)
END  ) 
from analytics_fashion.final_table_kb T2
where T1.subcatid = T2.subcatid  and 
T1.brandid = T2.brandid   and 
T1.UID >= (T2.UID)
) AS Remain2

FROM analytics_fashion.final_table_kb T1

Comment: You did not use an aggregate function in subquery: `Count()`, `Sum()`, `Avg()`, `Max()`, `Min()`. Try wrapping Case statement in `Sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would do this using variables.  Here is an example to calculate the row number:

```
select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by col;
```